Get the non-matching rows in SQL
We have two SQL tables
    and   .
Now, We have to do a merger of these two table in such a way that, table_1 seq_number which is not present in table_2, map with the tp_no = 0 Like this.

We have to create this in SQL table so it could be used further.
I am trying to achieve this by:
select distinct tar.c_Id,brd.Toucpoint,brd.sequence_number,tar.tot_Id,tar.tp_no
from table_2 tar 
inner join (
     select distinct c_Id,channel,sequence_number
     from table_1
) brd on tar.c_Id = brd.c_Id and tar.tp_no <> brd.sequence_number
where tar.tp_no = '0';

But this is not giving the desired output.

Where is F2F and MARKETO coming from? That's nowhere in your sample data. Also, please replace images with formatted text and tag your DBMS.

@Isolated - I have modified the output image. While creating this table, made a typo.

I used a CTE named SeqNotInTp_no to first select the sequences from Table_1 that do not exist as Tp_no in Table_2. I then joined SeqNotInTp_no with Tabel_2
WITH  SeqNotInTp_no as
(
  SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE Seq_Number NOT IN (SELECT tp_no FROM Table_2  WHERE Table_1.C_Id=Table_2.C_Id)  
)
SELECT SeqNotInTp_no.*,t2.Tot_Id, t2.Tp_no
FROM SeqNotInTp_no 
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t2.C_Id=SeqNotInTp_no.C_Id   
WHERE t2.Tp_no='0'  

fiddle



C_id
Toucpoint
Seq_Number
Tot_Id
Tp_no




Camp_1
F
1
388
0


Camp_1
Email
3
388
0




We would have different c_id and have different tp_no & seq_number conditions

@rns. Please provide more examples so I can understand the issue you describe.

@rns. Here is an example with a wider variety of C_id values https://dbfiddle.uk/mxG_BuMl

I think, this should work - convert your tp_no and then match
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM 
   Table_1 t1 inner join 
   (select *, (CASE WHEN tp_no = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new_tp_no from Table_2) t2    
       on t1.camp_1 = t2.camp_1 And t1.seq_number = t2.new_tp_no

Any further trimmings can be done by group by

This will also not work; with this we can only get 1 output, and it will also not work on all the C_Id

@rns not sure what "1output" means

Hello you can solve this using or full join or using exists operator:
Using Full join:
   with data as (
    select  t1.C_id, t1.Toucpoint, t1.Seq_Number, t2.Tot_Id, t2.Tp_no
     from tbl1 t1 full join tbl2 t2 on t1.Seq_Number=t2.tp_no and t1.C_id=t2.C_id
    )
    select * from (
    select c_id, toucpoint, seq_number, max(tot_id)over() as tot_id ,  max(tp_no)over()as tp_no
    from data
    where tot_id is null or c_id is null
    )a where c_id is not null;

Using exists oprator:
select *, (select  tot_id from tbl2 where t1.C_id=C_id and tp_no not in (select  Seq_Number from tbl1))as tot_id,
 (select tp_no from tbl2 where t1.C_id=C_id and tp_no not in (
select  Seq_Number from tbl1))as tp_no
from tbl1 t1
where not exists (select * from tbl2 where t1.Seq_Number=tp_no);

Hope it helps.

SELECT T1.*, tot_id, Tp_no
FROM   Table1 AS T1
       JOIN Table2 AS T2
          ON T1.C_Id = T2.C_Id AND (Seq_number = Tp_no OR Seq_number = 0)

not tested...

-- Only the rows that don't exist in Table2
SELECT 
    t1.C_Id, 
    t1.Toucpoint, 
    t1.Seq_number, 
    t2.tot_id, 
    t2.Tp_no
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON 
    t1.C_id = t2.C_Id
    AND t2.tp_no = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table_2 t3 
    WHERE t3.c_id = t1.c_id 
    AND t3.tp_no = t1.seq_number
);

-- All the rows
SELECT
    t1.C_id, 
    t1.Toucpoint, 
    t1.Seq_number, 
    t2.tot_id, 
    t2.Tp_no
FROM Table_1 t1  
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t1.C_Id, 
        t1.Seq_number, 
        ISNULL(t2.Tp_no, 0) AS Tp_no 
    FROM Table_1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON 
        t1.C_Id = t2.C_Id
        AND t1.Seq_number = t2.Tp_no 
) adjusted_tp_no ON 
    t1.C_id = adjusted_tp_no.C_Id
    AND t1.seq_number = adjusted_tp_no.seq_number
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON 
    t1.C_id = t2.C_Id
    AND adjusted_tp_no.tp_no = t2.Tp_no;


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
